# Visual Studio Community unit testing (c++)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unit-testing

I wanted to add unit tests to a software-project in Visual Studio Community.

I right-clicked on my project folder and created a new test project. Then I right clicked on my new Test Project and added a reference to my c++ project. How can I reference my source code in my test project?

The problem is, that I can't include anything from my c++ project (and therefore can't test anything from my code).

As I am new to C++: 
Are there any other plugins/extensions for unit testing you can recommend?

Many thanks in advance,

Comment: If it is anything like Visual Studio 2013, then you can add a reference to the project under test by going to "Project Properties > Configuration Properties > C/C++ > General > Additional Include Directories". You can add the path to the folder containing the code you wish to test there.

Comment: Which visual studio?

Comment: I included the project containing my source code in the project properties - now I can include my files.